# binding multiple events to one selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#action_button").click(function() {
```

How would I bind an onEnter event with a different selector to the same code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the logic to a common method and call that from everywhere.for onenter event,bind keyup and check for keycode 13.

```
$("#new_selector").keyup(function(event){
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which; // browser compatible
    if(keyCode === 13){
        do_something();
    }
});

$("#action_button").click(function() {
   do_something();
});

function do_something(){
//
}
```

Comment: For sure. Gotta love the community. Hopefully soon I can help others in the community once I reach the level of mastery I'm shooting for.

Answer (score 6):

Create a named function and use that instead of an anonymous function.

```
$("#action_button").click(processAction);
$("#otherSelector").otherEvent(processAction);

function processAction() {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Okay so I can now use multiple selectors for the same code? thanks man! Good info for sure! Happy New Years btw.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby if jfriend00's answer solved your problem please 'accept' his answer.

Comment: I accepted @dku.rajkumar's response. It was the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean add events on the same line chaining one selector?
as far as i know you have to have a brand new statement.
you could try:

$("#action_button").click(function() {...}).add('other-selector').onEnter...
but i dont know if that works at all.

Comment: This is clearly not what the OP is asking about.  The question says "different selector" and "same code".  With this, you would get "same selector" and "different code".